# Show private value from package to notebook

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I use this Manipulate in a package:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a1 x1], {x1, -2 Pi, 2Pi}], {a1, 1,5}, Text["y=a1 sin(x)"]];
```

In the notebook, near the slider that is created, there is `Pack Private a1`.
How can I write something istead of that? Or just `a1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a1 x1], {x1, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
  PlotLabel -> "y = sin(a1 x)"],
 {{a1, 1}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't see a1 but again Pack Private a1

Comment: @Ale1794 - Try starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: Put this code between ``Begin["MyPackage`Private`"]`` and `End[]` to see the problem

Comment: @BobHanlon I mixed you solution with the Shadowray one:
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a1 x1], {x1, -2 Pi, 2 Pi},
             PlotLabel -> "y = a*sin(x)"],
             {{a1, 1,"a"}, 1, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

Answer (score 1):

You can add any text label for `Manipulate` parameter like this:

```
Manipulate[
    Plot[Sin[a1 x1], {x1, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}], 
    {{a1, 1, "my label for a1"}, 1,  5}
    ]
```

This method does not depend on the `$Context` and will show the same label even when called from package (i.e. when your variable is called `` Pack`Private`a1 ``).

See also: examples on the [`Manipulate` help page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html).